# How to give back functionality while using MFSideMenu?

Tags: ios, objective-c

when we will navigate to another view controller. then using back button popviewcontroller property we can come to first view controller.

but what to do when we using MFSideMenu drawer. while clicking on drawer menu navigate to another screen. then how to come back on first view controller.

for navigating to another viewcontroller. I have used following code.

```
SCMainMenuViewController *scMainView = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"scMainMenuController"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scMainView];
[self.menuContainerViewController setCenterViewController:nav];
[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed completion:^{
   }];
```

Comment: have you tried [self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @channi I have already used this but not working

Comment: Your centerViewController is navigationController??, if it is, then try self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController.topViewController

Comment: my apologies I didn't noticed navigationController in your code before

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HomeView *Home = [[HomeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:Home];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
```